# Javascript Calculator for The Odin Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, calculator

When I run my code no problems populate in the console however, I cannot figure out why my equal operator is not working. I can press the numbers, operators, and equal button and it shows up on the screen but it will not calculate the problem. Can anyone help me figure out what is I am missing to get the function to work correctly?

```js
const screen = document.querySelector('.screen')
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear')
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers')
const operators = document.querySelectorAll('.operators')
const equal = document.querySelector('.equal')

let previousValue = ''
let currentValue = ''

let num1 = ''
let num2 = ''


numberButtons.forEach(function(numberButton) {
  numberButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    screen.textContent += numberButton.value;
    currentValue = parseInt(screen.innerText);

  })
})

function operate() {
  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = parseInt(num2);
  if (operators === '+') {
    num1 += num2;
  } else if (operators === '-') {
    num1 -= num2;
  } else if (operators === '*') {
    num1 *= num2;
  } else {
    num1 /= num2;
  }
}

operators.forEach(function(operators) {
  operators.addEventListener("click", function() {
    screen.textContent += operators.value;
    currentValue = (screen.innerText);

  })
})






equal.addEventListener("click", function() {
  screen.textContent += equal.value;
  currentValue = (screen.innerText);
  operate(operators, num1, num2)



})



clear.addEventListener('click', () => location.reload());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.calc {
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  color: #FB6F92;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 625px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div.container {
  background: #e7e7e7;
  width: 500px;
  height: 555px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #FB6F92;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
}

div.screen {
  border: 5px solid #FB6F92;
  color: black;
  background: #f8f8ff;
  width: 445px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

button.clear {
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFCCF9;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

button.clear:hover {
  background: #Ff9cee;
}

button.numbers {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.numbers:hover {
  background: #FB6F92;
}

button.operators {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #A4E7DF;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.operators:hover {
  background: #3bc6b6;
  #64d4c7
}

button.equal {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #D1B2EA;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.equal:hover {
  background: #b07cda;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Calculator TOP Project</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body style='background-color :#a0ddfb;'>
  <div class="calc"> Calculator</div>
  <div class="container">

    <br>
    <div class="screen" value="screen"></div>

    <button class="clear" onclick="clear();">Clear</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="7"> 7</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="8">8</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="9">9</button>
    <button class='operators' value="/"> &#247;</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="4">4</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="5">5</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="6">6</button>
    <button class='operators' value="*">    &#215;</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="1">1</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="2">2</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="3">3</button>
    <button class='operators' value="-">-</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value=".">.</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="0">0</button>
    <button class='equal' value="=">=</button>
    <button class='operators' value="+">+</button>

  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assign the values to num1 and num2. It looks like your calculator is mainly printing to screen. This will allow you to take a shortcut and use `eval` to parse that expression. But eventually you do want to program some logic into your exercise.

```js
const screen = document.querySelector('.screen')
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear')
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers')
const operators = document.querySelectorAll('.operators')
const equal = document.querySelector('.equal')

let previousValue = ''
let currentValue = ''

let num1 = ''
let num2 = ''


numberButtons.forEach(function(numberButton) {
  numberButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    screen.textContent += numberButton.value;
    currentValue = parseInt(screen.innerText);
  })
})

function operate() {
  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = parseInt(num2);
  if (operators === '+') {
    num1 += num2;
  } else if (operators === '-') {
    num1 -= num2;
  } else if (operators === '*') {
    num1 *= num2;
  } else {
    num1 /= num2;
  }
}

operators.forEach(function(operators) {
  operators.addEventListener("click", function() {
    screen.textContent += operators.value;
    currentValue = (screen.innerText);
  })
})

equal.addEventListener("click", function() {
  /*screen.textContent += equal.value;
  currentValue = (screen.innerText);
  operate(operators, num1, num2)
  */
  var x = eval("(" + screen.textContent + ")")
  screen.innerText = x;
})

clear.addEventListener('click', () => location.reload());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.calc {
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  color: #FB6F92;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 125px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div.container {
  background: #e7e7e7;
  width: 500px;
  height: 555px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #FB6F92;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
}

div.screen {
  border: 5px solid #FB6F92;
  color: black;
  background: #f8f8ff;
  width: 445px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

button.clear {
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFCCF9;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

button.clear:hover {
  background: #Ff9cee;
}

button.numbers {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.numbers:hover {
  background: #FB6F92;
}

button.operators {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #A4E7DF;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.operators:hover {
  background: #3bc6b6;
  #64d4c7
}

button.equal {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #D1B2EA;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.equal:hover {
  background: #b07cda;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Calculator TOP Project</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body style='background-color :#a0ddfb;'>
  <div class="calc"> Calculator</div>
  <div class="container">

    <br>
    <div class="screen" value="screen"></div>

    <button class="clear" onclick="clear();">Clear</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="7"> 7</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="8">8</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="9">9</button>
    <button class='operators' value="/"> &#247;</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="4">4</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="5">5</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="6">6</button>
    <button class='operators' value="*">    &#215;</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value="1">1</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="2">2</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="3">3</button>
    <button class='operators' value="-">-</button>
    <br>
    <button class='numbers' value=".">.</button>
    <button class='numbers' value="0">0</button>
    <button class='equal' value="=">=</button>
    <button class='operators' value="+">+</button>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```